# HVAC blower control in several rooms

Tags: hvac, blower

At my church we have lots of HVAC systems. Some of the systems condition several rooms. As you know, you can't make everyone happy at one time. The thin older ladies in one room are freezing and the overweight men in the next room are roasting. The solution is to close the vents in the cold room (Yeah, that's not how it should be done, but you don't argue with the women). The problem that occurs is that when too many vents get closed, the back pressure causes the tape holding a duct transition together comes apart and air goes where it doesn't need to go. Then when the vents are opened, the system leaks air and can't blow all of it into the rooms. Fixing the duct so that the tape can't blow off would be difficult, but the excess back pressure would still be a problem.

Budget is a big concern. How can this problem be resolved? One thought that comes to my mind is to have a spring loaded gate that dumps excess air into the hallway.

Answer (score 1):

Ducts shouldn't be held (or even sealed) with tape. That's an obsolete technique. For a quick repair, you might find that aluminum foil tape is robust enough to hold. Otherwise, clean the duct surface and use clear 100% silicone. Give it at least 4 hours to cure. 8-12 would be better. Note that silicone isn't paintable, so if you need that you might consider urethane caulk.

Really, an in-duct damper at the split to each room is best. You may need to get a tinbender involved, as special tools and techniques are sometimes required.

Finally, consider switching the occupants of the rooms. Sometimes the best solution is the simplest one.

Comment: The tape is aluminum foil. Not sure what the in-duct damper would do that the vent dampers don't already do. Except that the in-duct damper would not be easily accessible.

Comment: The damper would eliminate the pressure problem downstream. Isn't that the goal?